# SQL Connection Time out issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have web application which contains the class to connect sql server. I have written the connection class like below

```
public SqlConnection DbConnectSql()
{
    string str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ToString();
    _con = new SqlConnection(str);
    if (_con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        _con.Close();
    _con.Open();
   return _con;
}
```

When I am using the above code on the production server, some times the connection is not getting opened. The connection works fine after restarting the IIS. I have to do the IIS restart every two days. to work the sql connection. We didn’t get the exact exception of this issue.

To solve this, do we need to close the connection for all other cases except     “`_con.State == ConnectionState.Closed`”?  If we do so, is there any after affect for this code?

Comment: Im puzzled why a new connection would be seen to be open.. perhaps some of the problem is you make a new _con overwriting the old without closing it.

Answer (score 0):

Modify

```
 if (_con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            _con.Close();
        _con.Open();
```

in

```
 if (_con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                _con.Open();
```

and try.

Usually it's not good practice to check if a connection is open when you start it then close it immediately and reopen it immediately as there could be latency issues.

It makes much more sense to check if there is any connection open with that session (connection == Connection.Closed) and then, if it's closed, open it, else do nothing because I am already connected.

This way, beyond being more logically meaningful is also more concise.

Also, in your code, when you use your SqlConnection, wrap them in a

```
using(_con)
{
    //code here, sql stuff
};
```

statement, as it will manage itself all the closing and disposing connection stuff so you are sure when your sql logic is done everything gets disposed correctly without having to call Close and Dispose methods manually.

Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

> do we need to close the connection for all other cases

Sure, simply because all connections are created in a single Pool. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling

- Try to minimize connection creations (or reusing existing ones)
- After finish usage of it, call `con.Close()` then `con.Dispose()` to insure you free resources